# Image Streaming using QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, image, qt, streaming, qgraphicsview

I am trying to display images from a CameraLink Camera into a QGraphicsView.
I am using a ring buffer which get() and set() functions and two threads that consume or produce the images in this ring buffer.
This part works because I already had a successfull streaming using a QWidget. I want to use a QGraphicsView because I want to draw over those incoming images

I have a display class which is promoted to QGraphicsView, everytime an image is produced, a signal is emitted from the consumer thread to the following function:

```
void display::drawImage(ImageBW* image)
{
    firstImage = image;
    QRect rect;
    rect.setHeight(1000);
    rect.setWidth(2000);

    QApplication::postEvent(this->viewport(),new QPaintEvent(rect));
}
```

I have reimplemented the painEvent of the QGraphicsview class:

```
void display::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if(firstImage)
        _drawImage();
    event->setAccepted(true);
}
```

and the drawing function is:

```
void display::_drawImage()
{
    int w, h;
    if(img)
    {
        delete img;
        img = NULL;
    }
    w = firstImage->getSizeX();
    h = firstImage->getSizeY();
    unsigned char * udata = (unsigned char *)firstImage ->getData();
    img = new QImage(udata,w, h,QImage::Format_Grayscale8);

    pix_img = QPixmap::fromImage(*img);

    scene->clear();
    scene->addPixmap(pix_img);
    scene->setSceneRect(pix_img.rect());
    scene->update();
    update(); // I have tried here also setScene(scene)
}
```

In the above code, firstImage is an ImageBW* variable. ImageBW is where the image data from camera is stored.

I have also tried with QGraphicsItem and addItem() function but i get no Image. 
'scene' is initialized on the producer of this class and also the 'setScene(scene);' command is there.
The program stucks after a while so that probably means that this code produces stackoverflow.
Please I have tried everything i can think of, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to know whether your image data is incorrect or the way you try to show it is wrong. To prove that you get a valid image data just try to save your image right after you create it in `img = new QImage(...)` line. Just call `img->save("foo.png");` and check whether the "foo.png" image file has valid image data.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, i tried that and I have a sucessfull image. I also had successfull streaming by using a QWidget instead of QGraphicsView but there I had problems with zooming effects :) As i said I want to be able to draw the pixel value on top of the pixels of the images if the zoom becomes too big( I have already done that for one image using QGraphicsView but I couldnt do it using QWidget because I could not get accurate zooming)

Comment: If you overload `QGraphicsView::paintEvent()` and do not call the base class method prior or after your own rendering, then you by-pass the `QGraphicsScene` rendering. Somewhere in `display::paintEvent()`, `QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event)` should be called. May be, overloading [`QGraphicsView::drawBackground()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#drawBackground) is the even better candidate for overloading to overlay your image drawing with the scene rendering.

Comment: Yes , that was the problem, thanks